# Suppress section numbering in front matter for ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, books

I would like to show the sections of some chapters in the front matter part of the `book` class document in the table of contents. Problem is all the chapters in the front matter are numbered 0 and so their sections get the numbering like 0.1, 0.2. I want to suppress the numbers but show the section titles in the ToC. How can I achieve that?

Example:

```
           CONTENTS
% Front Matter
Preface
How to use the book
    Book organization
    Glossary

% Main Matter
Chapter 1 Test Chapter 1
    1.1 Test section 1
    1.2 Test section 2
Chapter 2 Test Chapter 2
    2.1 Test section 1
    2.2 Test section 2
```

Comment: Use the starred forms, `\section*{...}`

Comment: This will cause the sections to not appear on ToC

Comment: Would you please provide an MWE? Maybe something like \renewcommand\thesection{{}{}}% after \frontmatter works, but I do not want to try this in the only book class document I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` to get unnumbered sections in front matter and `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` to get numbered parts, chapters, sections und subsections in main matter:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xappto{\frontmatter}{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}}{}{}% unnumbered sections, subsections, subsubsections etc.
\xappto{\mainmatter}{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}}{}{}% numbered parts, chapters, sections, subsections

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{How to use the book}
\section{Book organization}
\section{Glossary}
\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. How about chapters in front matter?

Comment: Chapters in front matter are unnumbered by default, even if counter `secnumdepth` is `0` or bigger.